# Angular JS Accordion issue, sometimes it expands sometimes it wont

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion

Javascript:

```
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    // Variables privadas
    var links = this.el.find('.link');
    // Evento
    links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
}

Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
        $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

    if (!e.data.multiple) {
        $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
}   
var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
$scope.$apply();
        });
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Products</h3>                    
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <ul id="accordion" class="accordion" >
                  <li ng-repeat="(key, categoryType) in categories">

                    <div class="link">{{categoryType.name}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                      <li ng-repeat="item in categoryType[categoryType.name] track by $index" ng-click="getProductDetails(item)"><a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>                      
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Accordion sometimes expand sometimes wont, when I inspect the element nothing triggers no action at all, I am doing this on visualforce page.

Posting part of snippet from the entire code.

Thanks

Comment: I would discourage mixing Angular and jQuery as both are DOM manipulation frameworks and they don't work well together. You should try the [accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion) component from the [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) library.